# How to verify a contract on Arbiscan using hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have a problem when using hardhat to verify contract on Arbiscan. Everything were fine when I using this on Etherscan but on Arbiscan, I can't find any solution on Internet. Have anyone have any ideas?
Here is my config:

```
etherscan: {
   apiKey: process.env.ARBISCAN_APIKEY,
},
```

Here is the errors messages I facing:

> Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: An etherscan endpoint could not be found for this network. ChainID: 421611. The selected network is arbitrum_rinkeby
> Possible causes are:
>
> - The selected network (arbitrum_rinkeby) is wrong.
> - Faulty hardhat network config

Answer (score 0):

hardhat-etherscan likely does not have support for verifying on the arbitrum testnet (rinkeby). Alternatively, you can use a tool like [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol) to create a folder of contracts, which you can then use the [arbiscan GUI](https://arbiscan.io/verifyContract) to manually verify your contract.

Until hardhat-etherscan adds support for alternative networks, you're either going to have to do it manually, or fiddle around with the arbiscan API yourself

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have chainId on hardhat config and update hardhat

https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/blob/6c76e8dfd46ae1130a01decf0a7d2f751837b9b3/packages/hardhat-etherscan/src/network/prober.ts#L42

Answer (score 0):

Theres already support on arbiscan.io, just make sure you login and create an API KEY, and on hardhat config file add

```
...
etherscan: {
    apiKey: ARBITRUM_API_KEY
}
```